# custom vc elements won't render on translated pages wpml plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml, visual-composer

I have created a custom post type for a slider posts and then a custom visual composer element to gather those posts from that post type and then assemble it to create a slider but it won't render on the translated pages like if I create a german page, the custom vc element (slider) won't render or show unto that page. Any help, ideas please?

here's the vc element

```
<?php class axada_custom_elements extends WPBakeryShortCode {
    // Element Init
    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'axada_custom_elements_mapping' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'axada_slider', array( $this, 'axada_slider_html' ) );
    }

// Element Mapping
public function axada_custom_elements_mapping() {

    // Stop all if VC is not enabled
    if ( !defined( 'WPB_VC_VERSION' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Map the block with vc_map()
    vc_map( 
        array(
            'name' => __('Axada Slider', 'text-domain'),
            'base' => 'axada_slider',
            'description' => __('Axada Slider', 'text-domain'), 
            'category' => __('Axada Elements', 'text-domain'),   
            "as_parent" => array('except' => ''), // Use only|except attributes to limit child shortcodes (separate multiple values with comma)
            "content_element" => true,
            "show_settings_on_create" => true,
            "is_container" => true,
            'icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/img/axada-short-logo.png',
            'params' => array(   

                array(
                    'type' => 'textfield',
                    'holder' => 'div',
                    'class' => 'title-class',
                    'heading' => __( 'Slider ID', 'text-domain' ),
                    'param_name' => 'slider_id',
                    'value' => __( '', 'text-domain' ),
                    'description' => __( 'Slider ID', 'text-domain' ),
                    'admin_label' => false,
                    'weight' => 0,
                    'group' => 'Custom Group',
                ),  

                array(
                    'type' => 'textfield',
                    'holder' => 'div',
                    'class' => 'title-class',
                    'heading' => __( 'Slider Classes', 'text-domain' ),
                    'param_name' => 'slider_class',
                    'value' => __( '', 'text-domain' ),
                    'description' => __( 'Slider Classes', 'text-domain' ),
                    'admin_label' => false,
                    'weight' => 0,
                    'group' => 'Custom Group',
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'textfield',
                    'holder' => 'div',
                    'class' => 'title-class',
                    'heading' => __( 'Slider Custom Styles', 'text-domain' ),
                    'param_name' => 'slider_custom_styles',
                    'value' => __( '', 'text-domain' ),
                    'description' => __( 'Slider Custom Styles', 'text-domain' ),
                    'admin_label' => false,
                    'weight' => 0,
                    'group' => 'Custom Group',
                ),  
            ),
        )

    );
}

// Element HTML
public function axada_slider_html( $atts ) {
    // Params extraction
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'slider_id'   => '',
                'slider_class' => '',
                'slider_custom_styles' => '',
            ), 
            $atts
        )
    );

    $slider_custom_styles = $slider_custom_styles !== '' ? 'style="'.$slider_custom_styles.'"' : '';
    // Fill $html var with data
    //query for slider
    ob_start();
//query for slider
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'axada_slider',
    'meta_key' => '_arrangement_value_key',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',                
    'order'         => 'ASC',           
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    );
$slider = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $slider->have_posts() ) :
//start slider
?>
<section class="kenburns image-slider slider-all-controls controls-inside pt0 pb0 height-70 vid-bg bg-dark" id="home-slider-wrapper">
    <ul<?php echo $slider_id !== '' ? ' id="'.$slider_id.'" ' : ' '; ?>class="slides<?php echo $slider_class !== '' ? ' '.$slider_class : ''?>"<?php echo $slider_custom_styles !== '' ? ' style="'.$slider_custom_styles.'" ' : ''; ?> >
        <?php while ( $slider->have_posts() ) : $slider->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
           <?php if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_axada_slider_video_value_key', true ) && get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_axada_slider_video_value_key', true )!==''){?>
                <div class="player" data-video-id="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_axada_slider_video_value_key', true ); ?>" data-start-at="0"></div>
                <div class="background-image-holder bg-size-cover">
                    <img alt="image" class="background-image" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" />
                </div>

           <?php }else{ ?>
                 <div class="background-image-holder bg-size-cover">
                    <img alt="image" class="background-image" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="container v-align-transform">
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <div class="full-width divider mb-xs-64"></div>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
           <?php } ?>   
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
</section>
<?php 
//end slider
endif;
return ob_get_clean();

}
```